# Application menu disappears when using QApplication in plugin even with qt_mac_set_native_menubar(false)

Tags: qt, plugins, acrobat

I am working an Acrobat plugin (SDK Acrobat 8) which uses Qt Widgets. It works fine with Qt 4.3.4. After upgrading to Qt 4.6.4 Carbon, it is no longer possible to see Acrobat's menu if QApplication is instantiated.

```
int argc = 0;
(void)new QApplication(argc, 0, true);

qt_mac_set_native_menubar(false);
```

With those 3 lines, the Acrobat menu does not load, neither can it be quit other than with a force quit.
There are no warning messages, everything seems to be working fine, except that is really does not.
Without those 3 lines, acrobat works well as long as not widgets are created (see QApplication doc).

Why?
Thanks for whatever information you may have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
qApp->setAttribute(Qt::AA_MacPluginApplication,true);
```

right after you create the `QApplication`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I though qt_mac_set_native_menubar(false); was supposed to have the same behaviour.

Comment: Not quite, but that line also does set native menubar to false, so that can be removed.